# fire webViewDidFinishLoad before document.onload

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I need to inject some js code on my webpage being loaded in my UIWebView before any other script is executed. Unfortunately it seems that HTML `document.onload` is executed before objective-c `webViewDidFinishLoad` callback.

Check this test code out:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    webView.delegate = self;

    [webView loadHTMLString:@"<body onload=\"alert('this is from html')\"></body>" baseURL:nil];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"alert('this is from obj-c')"];
}
```

Message "this is from html" is always shown before message "this is from obj-c".
I need to get the other way around considering that I cannot control my html page, so I have to assume there's a `document.onload` function being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...ok found...

I need to use `webViewDidStartLoad` instead of `webViewDidFinishLoad`.

Surprisingly to me, jscode injected during `webViewDidStartLoad` callback is available to the loaded HTML page. This means to me that the UIWebView javascript engine is not reset after `webViewDidStartLoad` which is fine to me.